# LIBRE OFFICE / EXCEL how to get data from a column and join with string

Tags: excel, libreoffice

How do i do something like for example:

COL(C2).VALUE + ",\n" + COL(D2).VALUE + ",\n" + COL(E2).VALUE

in excel or libre office.

I want to concatenate column values across a row into 1 column with a seperator of my choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel:

```
=C2 & CHAR(10) & D2 & CHAR(10) & E2
```

Answer (score 0):

In excel, I always use this function from http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/udfs/multicat.html :

```
  '*****************************************
  'Purpose: Concatenate all cells in a range
  'Inputs:  rRng - range to be concatenated
  '         sDelimiter - optional delimiter
  '            to insert between cell Texts
  'Returns: concatenated string
  '*****************************************

  Public Function MultiCat( _
        ByRef rRng As Excel.Range, _
        Optional ByVal sDelim As String = "") _
             As String
     Dim rCell As Range
     For Each rCell In rRng
        If rCell.Value <> "" Then
         MultiCat = MultiCat & sDelim & rCell.Text
         End If
     Next rCell
     MultiCat = Mid(MultiCat, Len(sDelim) + 1)
  End Function
```

You enter it like this:

```
=multicat(A1:A5,",")
```

I can't offer much advice on Libre - I don't have it - but I'm sure you could find a similar custom function for Libre.

Good Luck.